# PHP get both array value and array key

Tags: php, arrays, key

I want to run a for loop through an array and create anchor elements for each element in the array, where the key is the text part and the value is the URL.

How can I do this please?

Thank you.

Comment: http://de.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: As for a "for" and not "foreach", you could probably walk the array with next() and grab the key with key()

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This should do it

```
foreach($yourArray as $key => $value) {
    //do something with your $key and $value;
    echo '<a href="' . $value . '">' . $key . '</a>';
}
```

Edit: As per Capsule's comment - changed to single quotes.

Comment: It's another 13 minutes until I can set it as the correct answer, but I will.

Comment: If you want to edit the value in the loop, change `$value` to `&$value`. Then, any changes you make to `$value` in the loop will affect the original array. For more information, see PHP's page on references: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: -1 for using single quotes in HTML code. Would break validation with some doctypes (like XHTML)

Comment: @Capsule - I'll be honest I didn't even know that was the case.  Coming from ASP.NET background where you simply assume the page won't validate, so I never bothered to check things like that.  I ended up using the above syntax out of sheer convenience in PHP

Comment: @Marek btw PHP is faster when using single quotes because it doesn't try to interpret any variables or special chars inside in the string. So you should definitely use that ;-) I would also concatenate `. "\n"` for readability purposes when viewing HTML source code, even if I definitely don't recommend using echo in the middle of a PHP script.

Answer (score 29):

For some specific purposes you may want to know the current key of your array without going on a loop. In this case you could do the following:

```
reset($array);
echo key($array) . ' = ' . current($array);
```

The above example will show the Key and the Value of the first record of your Array.

The following functions are not very well known but can be pretty useful in very specific cases:

```
key($array);     //Returns current key
reset($array);   //Moves array pointer to first record
current($array); //Returns current value
next($array);    //Moves array pointer to next record and returns its value
prev($array);    //Moves array pointer to previous record and returns its value
end($array);     //Moves array pointer to last record and returns its value
```

Comment: I think this is the way SPL does it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$array = array(
    'Google' => 'http://google.com',
    'Facebook' => 'http://facebook.com'
);

foreach($array as $title => $url){
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a template context, it would be:

```
<?php foreach($array as $text => $url): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You shouldn't write your HTML code inside your PHP code, hence avoid echoing a bunch of HTML.

This is not filtering anything, I hope your array is clean ;-)