# PHP Array - Get the key value

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP get both array value and array key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745582/php-get-both-array-value-and-array-key)

I am using Codeigniters' form_checkbox() method.

Using a foreach loop I am creating the form_checkbox and the forms' label. This is all fine, But I need to get the value from the array.

My array setup is as follows :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Animals
    [2] => Art and Culture
    [3] => Children
    [4] => Disability
    [5] => Disaster Relief
    [6] => Domestic Violence
);
```

My PHP code is as follows :

```
<?php foreach($interests as $interest)
        {
            echo form_checkbox('user_interests[]', $interest);
            echo "<label>$interest</label>";
        }
?>
```

This produces HTML Like :

> ```
> <input type="checkbox" value="Animals" name="user_interests[]">
> ```

What I would like it to be is the value = "1", "2" etc from the Array key.

How do I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<?php foreach($interests as $k=> $interest)
        {
           $data= array('name'=>'user_interests[]', 'value'= $k)
            echo form_checkbox($data);
            echo "<label>$interest</label>";
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your loop to be:

```
foreach($interests as $key => $interest) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
foreach($interests as $key => $interest)
```

Answer (score 2):

change your php code to this:

```
foreach($interests as $key => $interest)
{
    echo form_checkbox('user_interests[]', $key);
    echo "<label>$interest</label>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
foreach ($interests as $key => $interest) {
  echo form_checkbox("user_interests[$key]", $interest);
  echo "<label>$interest</label>";
}
```