# PHP save array results in variable

Tags: php, arrays

let me say I have an array like this:

```
$testarray = array('abc'=>'123',
              'def'=>'456',
              'ghi'=>'789'
);
```

For an operation I need the single values of the array in variables. I would like to loop through the array and have something like this:

```
new cmdOption("cn", $arrayvaluefirstcolumn, "User")

new cmdOption("mod", "text=".$arraysecondcolumn, "expression")
```

So, I would like to have 'abc' as $arrayvaluefirstcolumn and '123' as $arrayvaluesecondcolumn in the first loop. And in the second loop, I would like to have 'def' as $arrayvaluefirstcolum and '456' as $arrayvaluesecondcolumn and so on.

I am not sure how to loop through the array to get the desired result and store it in the variables. Is this possible? Can you give me some advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP get both array value and array key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745582/php-get-both-array-value-and-array-key)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do is to loop through your array.

```
$testarray = array(
    'abc' => '123',
    'def' => '456',
    'ghi'=>'789'
);

foreach ($testArray as $key => $value) {
    new cmdOption("cn", $key, "User");
    new cmdOption("mod", "text=".$value, "expression");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($testarray as $key => $value)
{
    //returns 'abc', 'def', 'ghi'
    $arrayvaluefirstcolumn = $key;
    //returns '123', '456', '789'
    $arrayvaluesecondcolumn = $value;
}
```