# Get index of array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

**Given:**

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
}
```

How do I get the current index of `$rows` during any given iteration, **without a separate count variable**?

**What I tried:**

```
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
}
```

**EDIT BELOW**

But `$key` gives me the current index of `$row`, not the current index of `$rows`.

What I want to do is:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if(current_index($rows) == 0){
        // do something
    }
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
}
```

To my knowledge, PHP doesn't have a `current_index()` function or something like it.

Here's what `$rows` looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [firstname] => Firstname one
            [lastname] => Lastname one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [firstname] => Firstname two
            [lastname] => Lastname two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [firstname] => Firstname three
            [lastname] => Lastname three
        )
)
```

Comment: 1) Have you echo'ed `$key` in the loop and are you sure it is not what you want? 2) Please make a little example with an array what you get now as output and what you expected to get

Comment: This seems to be unclear `But this gives me the current index of $row, not the current index of $rows.`

Comment: @Exception `throw new Exception("Unclear question");`

Comment: @Rizier123 check out my edits

Comment: @FastTrack So your problem is that `$rows` is an associative array and you want to use it as an enumerated array?

Comment: @Rizier123 no, all I want to know is: on any given iteration, what is the current index of `$rows`

Comment: @FastTrack That is `$key` from the foreach loop. (Otherwise make an example with an array)

Comment: @FastTrack `$key` literally is the "current index". It's unclear of what you're trying to do, if you are not wanting to use it as an enumerated array.

Comment: @BrandonWhite `$key` is the current index of `$row` NOT the current index of `$rows`, which is what I want.

Comment: @Rizier123 check out my most recent edit... I included what `$rows` looks like.

Comment: @FastTrack No, `$key` is the current index of `$rows`, which you are iterating. ((Otherwise make an example of the current output + expected output with the shown example array))

Comment: @Rizier123 ahh yes it is! Thanks! I was messed up... coding while sick = not good.

Comment: @FastTrack [Haunted by shame +1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3933332)

Comment: Above suggested solution will not work for string key value pair.. And to make this work we have to add index externally which is I guess cumbersome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP get both array value and array key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745582/php-get-both-array-value-and-array-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing the array **value** as an array. That's why it is giving you `$row['id']`

You need to use `$key` as that is the value of your current index in the `$rows` array.

When you use `foreach($rows as $key => $row)` this is what it is practically doing:

- `$rows` - input array to loop through
- `$key` - key of your current location in the first dimensional array
- `$row` - value of your current location in the first dimensional array

Comment: What if array contains string keys ?

Comment: I this he is asking for integer keys like 1,2,3 and not like string indexes

Comment: It will still work for string indexes. It just won't be a 0, 1, 2.. etc. It would be the Associative Index.

Answer (score 1):

Well $key will give current array key which may be string so I think this following will be possible solution

```
$i=0;
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) { 
echo $row['id']; 
echo $row['firstname']; 
echo $row['lastname']; 
echo $i;
$i++;
}
```

Comment: As stated in my question, I'd like to accomplish this without using a separate count variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use associative array

```
$rows = array("id"=>"id","firstname"=>"firstname","lastname"=>"lastname")
foreach ($rows as $key=>$row) {
    if($key == "firstname"){ 
        // do something
    }
}
```