# foreach in php removes the key

Tags: php

I use this code for the loop:

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['accessories'] as $accessory) : ?>

    <?php var_dump($accessory); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The problem is that now I can access the content of each accessory but without knowing the id of that accessory, because the original array look like this:

```
[accessories] => Array
    (
        [63] => Array
            (
                [price] => 15000
                [name] => Product 2
            )

        .
        ..
        ...

    )
```

And the 63 is lost ;(

Any idea how to get the 63 too?

Comment: `foreach($x as $key => $value)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33154877/3933332 next one... (asked 30min ago)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP get both array value and array key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745582/php-get-both-array-value-and-array-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['accessories'] as $key => $accessory) : 

    echo $key;                 // prints id 63
    echo $accessory['price'];  // prints price
    echo $accessory['name'];   // prints names 

   endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: where are php tags? for $key and other 2 echo's?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add $key to your foreach loop

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['accessories'] as $key => $accessory) : ?> 
<?php var_dump($accessory); ?> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This will give key 63 which you are looking for..