# Accessing data from DB

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting data from database and putting it in a variable `$data`. If I'll `print_r($data)`, I'll get something like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Bob
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Mike
        )
)
```

It has more `[key] => value` in each of them, and obviously it doesn't end on `[1]`.

I'm using `foreach()` like that:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
   foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
       //code
   }
}
```

I have two question regards all the above:

1) Is there less complex technique to get the `$key` and `$value`?

2) If, for example, I want to output only the `[name]`, how would I access it? 
The `$key[placeholder]` while placeholder is a number is outputting the letter number value of the `$key`.

Comment: `$item` is an __object__. In your case you __cannot__ iterate over object. Read more about objects in php manual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP get both array value and array key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745582/php-get-both-array-value-and-array-key)

Comment: Thank you u_mulder, but can you please tell me how to get the `[name]` only, for example?

Comment: Masivuye, it is not a duplicate, you can see for your self I am using the same `$key => $value`. It doesn't answer my questions at all

Comment: When you retrieve the data from the database, you may be able to get it back as an array rather than objects, this will make life a lot easier.  Add the retrieval code here and that may help to solve your problem

Comment: `$item` is an object, so use `$item->name` to get its name.

Comment: @NigelRen can you post an example please? Because I will need to push some of the data back to the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array with object, so if you want only the name:

```
$name_list = array();

foreach ($data as $obj) {
    $name_list[] = $obj->name;
}
```

This way you will have an array with only the name of each object.

So to summarize :

You loop through an array of obj, so to access the properties  of each object just do :

```
$obj->/* the properties */;
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I do exactly like you, I'm getting: `ArrayArrayArrayArray`...

Comment: You do `foreach ($data as $obj) { ... }` with `$data` the array you show in your post?

Comment: Look, when I use: `$name_list[] = $obj->name;` and then `echo $name_list;` I'm getting the `ArrayArrayArrayArray`. But, if I use: `echo $obj->name;` I'm getting the results... Why is that?

Comment: It's because `$name_list` is an array (so you can't "echo" it, try a `var_dump($name_list)` and `$obj->name` the properties name of the current obj in your loop

Comment: Oh... So, I need to set the `$name_list` outside the loop, and then output it with `json_encode`? Is there a better way, perhaps(to output, get access to, etc)?

Comment: Well, in my example the `$name_list` was outside the loop ! And I don't understand your question : you asked how to get access to the `name` of each object, I think I anwser your question no? If you have an other question please edit your question or ask a new one because it's not clear what you want now :)